# installation of clang on ubuntu18.04?

Tags: 18.04, clang

I am trying to install clang on ubuntu 18.04. I have done the following:

going to the source of llvm making a directory build and executed cmake -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS=clang -G "Unix Makefiles" ../llvm command.

after executing that command when I executed make command I got the following error:

make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

can anyone help me?

Comment: Hacks like building everything you install from source won't help because your package management is hosed. You'll never be able to do much with your zombie operating system until you motivate yourself to fix your package management.

Answer (score 1):

If you want install Clang then just run this command : sudo apt install clang